# geth can't connect to node

Tags: go-ethereum

When I open Ethereum, I get an 'Ethereum node connection error. I'm using 0-8-10. Any ideas?

[image: this is the error I get]

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem for a long time. The trick was to download and run Geth from https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/ by itself before attempting to open Ethereum wallet or Mist and then let them sync.

Hope this helps!